# Empty IN sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

if I have this sql:

```
SELECT A FROM B WHERE C IN 
(
   SELECT D FROM E
)
```

If my internal select don't return any result (0 rows) my where statement will be true or false?

I'm using SQL Server

Comment: @zerkms I see... "_my where statement will_" so the OP is asking specifically about the WHERE condition (which is falsy), not the outer statement.

Comment: @Zane: **this** particular statement **is**, since it's not a correlated subquery.

Comment: Still results in search of a table for the results. Not equivalent to false.

Comment: @Zane: it's not about results of the search (?) it's about the value of `C IN (...)` expression, which is either `true` or `false` for the whole result set.

Comment: @Zane: `IN` operator doesn't return `not found` it returns either `false` or `true`

Comment: @Zane: excuse me, what? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx `Result Types: **Boolean**` Please stop wasting your (and my) time.

Comment: @zerkms I think there is a communication gap here as we are both agreeing with what Gordon is saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT A
FROM B
WHERE C IN (SELECT D FROM E);
```

The `where` statement is quite simple.  It filters out rows there is no match between `B.C` and `E.D`.  By your statement, there is no match, so all rows are filtered out.  The query returns no rows.

The `where` statement is not "true" or "false" in general.  It is "true" or "false" for a given row in `B` (in this case).  With no matches, the `where` clause will be uniformly false for all rows.

Comment: "The `where` statement is quite simple. It returns rows when there is a match between " --- may be poorly worded, but from this phrase one might think that "`where` statement" returns rows by itself.

Comment: @zerkms . . . I know what you are saying (and I changed the wording).  The problem is that I can't think of a good word to mean the opposite of "filter out".  "A `where` clause filters in rows that match the conditions" isn't quite right.

Comment: I personally think that "A `WHERE` clause filters rows" is a perfect wording.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the tables for the moment and think about what this does:

```
SELECT 'Yes' WHERE 1 IN (SELECT 1 WHERE 1=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither, if the inner query returns no rows, you won't get any results returned.  Selecting anything from an empty set will give you an empty set.  IMO an empty set is neither true nor false in and of itself, only when compared to something else.  So if the question is "will I get any results", then the answer is false.

Comment: "my **where statement** will be true or false" --- obviously it will be `false`

Comment: This can be a comment rather than answer.

Comment: @zerkms `WHERE`s aren't true or false, but determine WHICH rows match the criteria.

Comment: @JNK: `WHERE` clause (its expression) is evaluated to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, which determines whether current row matches the conditions or not

Comment: @zerkms correct, for a given RECORD.  It's not accurate to say the `Where clause will be false` unless you use something like `WHERE 1 = 0`.  No rows will match the criteria.

Comment: @JNK: please read the question once again. In this given answer we can tell that the expression is **always** evaluated to `FALSE`

Comment: @zerkms no we can't because these are tables.  No rows match the current data but tomorrow who knows.

Comment: @JNK: OP has asked about a particular case. I don't see a reason to not give a particular answer to that, without going further about theoretical possibility of having rows there or a comet colliding with Earth.

Comment: @Zane: it is the case - it's not a correlated subquery, so its result doesn't depend on the current row column values. So the `WHERE` expression value is constant to the whole resultset. "you're still looking at this wrong" --- there is your opinion and a wrong one, indeed.

Comment: wow, sorry didn't meant to start a holy war here.  Move along, nothing to see.